# How do I check an OWIN request before HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is set?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have an OWIN setup for my webapi2 site that uses Bearer tokens. Everything works, but I have now need to implement a security check.

Here's what I need to accomplish

1. Add a new claim when creating an identity that stores the RemoteIpAddress. This part I figured out already.
2. Check each incoming request that uses **bearer** tokens, and check if the current ip address matches the one set in the token. Not sure where the best place is to do this.

I was going to place my check in custom AuthorizeAttribute, but it felt out of place.

Is it possible to check OWIN requests using OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, and cancel authentication if the condition is not met? I really have no idea where the actual check is taking place to verify/decrypt the bearer token, and if possible, would like a hook or override to tap into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an owin middleware which checks the Ip adress as the first step in the chain.
Place it as the first middleware being attached to the IAppBuilder to make sure it will invoke before the rest of the chain

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            if (!IsIpAdressOk(context.Request)) //if the ip is invalid, stop the process and just return a response to the client
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Get lost!");
            }
            return Next.Invoke(context); //if the ip is correct then continue to the next middleware
        });

        ...add OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and the rest here   
    }
}
```

Great blog about Owin middlewares [here](http://blog.2mas.xyz/owin-middleware/)

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for. Thank you!